# Windows 10 等のクライアント OS で DHCP サーバの構築は可能か？

Tags: windows

Windows Serverではない通常のWindows10やWindows11上でDHCPサーバを構築する事は可能でしょうか？
Open DHCP Serverと言うソフトを導入すればできそうですが、Windows Serverと同じ標準のソフトはないという認識で間違っていませんか？

Comment: たとえできても EULA 違反の可能性大です。

Answer (score 2):

> Windows Serverではない通常のWindows10やWindows11上でDHCPサーバを構築する事は可能でしょうか？

標準機能としては用意されていませんが、サードパーティ製のアプリケーションなどを使用して実現することは可能です。ただし、プライベートな環境ならともかく、業務などで使用する場合はライセンス等への注意が必要です。
私は以前(Windows2000時代)マイクロソフトに問い合わせたことがありますが、その際は「Windows標準の機能以外を使用してサーバ機能を持たせた場合、同時接続ライセンス等は適用されない」という回答をもらいました。しかし、これらの規約は頻繁に改訂されますので、現時点での正確なライセンスの解釈はマイクロソフトに問い合わせて確認することが一番です。

> Open DHCP Serverと言うソフトを導入すればできそうですが、Windows Serverと同じ標準のソフトはないという認識で間違っていませんか？

サーバ用途としてはWindows Serverシリーズを使用しろ、というのがマイクロソフトのスタンスですので、現在ではクライアントOS向けのマイクロソフト製DHCPサーバソフトはないでしょう。